# Select special value in json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this JSON information:

```
{
"update_id":123456789,
"message":{
"message_id":93,
"from":{"id":101010101,"first_name":"Mahdi"},
"chat":{"id":101010101,"first_name":"Mahdi","type":"private"},
"date":1486137773,"text":"test"
    }
        }
```

I want select "id" value in "from" and check if it is correct (ex:101010101) do something.

first I used `json_decode` and 2 `foreach` statement inside together but it doesn't work and I'm confused. please comment correct code.

Comment: You don't need any `foreach`, just `$decoded['from']['id']`.

Comment: @deceze yeah finally I found the solution. $json["message"]["from"]["id"]; is correct. you forgot use "message" :)